# How do I pass a "#" in an URL using JS?

Tags: javascript

Why if using `#` in URL with JS it returns ''/false?

```
var el = '#string with number character -> #'   
el = el.replace(/[']/g, '&#039;');
el = el.replace(/[&#35;]/g, '&#039;');

xmlhttp.open("GET","process_add_article.php?&title=" + (el),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode a string on the url there is a native method to do so:

```
var el = '#string with number character -> #'; 
el = encodeURI(el);
```

I am not sure this will accomplish what you are looking for though, the url will be:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","process_add_article.php?&title=#string%20with%20number%20character%20-%3E%20#",true);
```

Which means the title parameter is empty, because the server will ignore the hash (#)

Comment: Coolt it works but when trying to save `!@#$%^&*()_+~[];'\,./{}"|:<>?` it gives me `!@#$%^&amp;*()_+~[];&#039;,./{}&quot;|:&lt;&gt;?`

Comment: why do you want `#` in your ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Because # specifies a fragment identifier. Fragment identifiers are entirely client side entities and as such are not sent to the server. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`Numeric Character Reference`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) and not [`Percent-Encoding`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for URIs.

You may want to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead.

```
var el = '#string with number character -> #'; 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "process_add_article.php?&title=" + encodeURIComponent(el), true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Not to be confused with [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) which doesn't encode `#`, `+` and `=` characters.